# Explicitly define referenced collection in a schema

Tags: meteor

I'm using the Meteor SimpleSchema package. Unfortunately its documentation is lacking an explanation on how to reference documents using Mongo.ObjectID so I'm wondering how it's done. In Mongoose, I'd have something like this:

```
BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Author'
    }
});
```

Where `ref: 'Author'` tells the BookSchema that the author ObjectId  will come from the Author model. In SimpleSchema, I'd have this:

```
BookSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    author: {
        type: Mongo.ObjectID
    }
});
```

Now what's left is to tell this schema that the Mongo.ObjectID here will come from the Authors collection and this is where I'm stuck. How do I do that?

Comment: SimpleSchema is just a schema validation tool, not an ORM. It just checks that all the fields have the correct type and structure. If you want to ensure that a referenced id actually exists in the referenced collection, you could create a custom validation rule that checks for the existence of the referenced document.

Comment: Oh, thanks. That's clear now.